# How to transform a term into a list in Prolog

Tags: parsing, prolog

How can i transform a term like: 3 * y * w * t^3 in a list made of: List = [3, *, y,...], without using the following predicate:

```
t2l(Term, List) :-
    t2l_(Term, List-X),
    X = [].
t2l_(Term, [F|X]-X) :-
    Term =.. [F],
    !.
t2l_(Term, L1-L4) :-
    Term =.. [F, A1, A2],
    t2l_(A1, L1-L2),
    L2 = [F|L3],
    t2l_(A2, L3-L4).
```

Is there a simple way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Prolog, everything that *can* be expressed by **pattern matching** *should* be expressed by pattern matching.

In your case, this is difficult, because you cannot collectively distinguish the *integers* from other arising terms by pattern matching with the **defaulty** representation you are using.

In the following, I am not solving the task completely for you, but I am showing how you *can* solve it once you have a **clean** representation.

As always when describing a *list* in Prolog, consider using [dcg](/questions/tagged/dcg) notation:

```
term_to_list(y) --> [y].
term_to_list(w) --> [w].
term_to_list(t) --> [t].
term_to_list(i(I)) --> [I].
term_to_list(A * B) -->
        term_to_list(A),
        [*],
        term_to_list(B).
term_to_list(A^B) -->
        term_to_list(A),
        [^],
        term_to_list(B).
```

In this example, I am using `i(I)` to symbolically represent the integer `I`.

Sample query and result:

```
?- phrase(term_to_list(i(3)*y*w*t^i(3)), Ls).
Ls = [3, *, y, *, w, *, t, ^, 3].
```

I leave converting the defaulty representation to a clean one as an easy exercise.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks mat for answering, i forgot to close the question. However i have created a new predicate that solve the problem:

```
term_string(Term, X),
string_codes(X, AList),
ascii_to_list(AList, Y).

ascii_to_list([X | Xs], [Y | Out]) :-
    X >= 48,
    X =< 57,
    !,
    number_codes(Y, [X]),
    ascii_to_list(Xs, Out).
ascii_to_list([X | Xs], [Y | Out]) :-
    char_code(Y, X),
    ascii_to_list(Xs, Out).
ascii_to_list([], []).
```

Comment: Try the most general query: `?- term_list(Term, List).` This gives you only *one* answer, which omits many valid solutions. With the version I posted, you can use: `?- phrase(term_to_list(T), Ls).` and **generate** as many valid answers as you want. I highly recommend to make your program as general as you can, so that you truly benefit from the declarative paradigm.